# Checking if NSOpenPanel returns a directory

Tags: cocoa

Trying to ascertain if NSOpenPanel has returned a file or dir

I've use the example code from Apple for fileExistsAtPath: and it works fine for fontPath
but doesn't seem to work for openpanel
not sure if I'm doing the right thing with getting the NSString from NSURL - I'm still a Cocoa newbie

It does indicate a Semantic issue
 Sending 'const BOOL *' (aka 'const signed char *') to parameter of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') discards qualifiers

Any help please

```
- (IBAction)openImage: (id)sender
{
    // present open panel...

NSString *    extensions = @"tiff/tif/TIFF/TIF/jpg/jpeg/JPG/JPEG/CR2";
NSArray *     types = [extensions pathComponents];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

//===================================
// example just to see if it works!!
NSArray *subpaths;   
BOOL isDir;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] == 1) {
    NSString *fontPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Fonts"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fontPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        NSLog(@"======= fontPath = %@", fontPath);          
    }
}
//============================================

// Let the user choose an output file, then start the process of writing samples
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:types];
[openPanel setCanSelectHiddenExtension:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:_window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
            // user did select an image...

        NSLog(@"URL = %@",[openPanel URL]);
        NSString *workFile = [[openPanel URL] absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"workFile %@",workFile);
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:workFile isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
            NSLog(@"======== It's a dir=======");
        }


         [self openImageURL: [openPanel URL]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: fileExistsAtPath will always check the file exist or not. So you can put one else condition here if fileExistsAtPath returns true then print it is a file or else inside else condition print it is a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a block references a local (stack) variable declared outside of the block itself then:

- a *constant* of the same type and name as the local variable is added to the block; and
- the current *value* of that local variable is used as the value of the block's constant

This is why you get an error referring to `const BOOL` as you are attempting to pass the address of the block's constant `isDir` where the address of a non-constant is expected.

You can pass `isDir` to the block as a *variable*, using the `__block` qualifier on its declaration, which means that uses of `isDir` within the block refer to *exactly the same variable* as the one declared outside the block.

However from your comments this does not appear to be what you need either, rather you just want a variable local to the block to use in a method call and `if` statement. For that just declare a variable within the block. You are already declaring `NSString *workFile` within the block, just declare a local boolean the same way.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

See [The __block Storage Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html). You are passing a reference to `isDir` to `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:`, which is modifying the `isDir` variable and the `isDir` variable is copied by the block that you are passing as a `completionHandler`.

From [The __block Storage Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html):

> You can specify that an imported variable be mutable—that is,
>   read-write— by applying the __block storage type modifier.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the problem is to do with there being a block. Have read up some documentation on blocks, can't say I fully understand the concept - this is my first real attempt at Cocoa :}
I've tried declaring 
    __block BOOL isDir;
in various places, to no avail.

How do I actually do this?

I just want to display an NSOpenPanel
If the user chooses a file then open it.
If they choose a dir, then do something else.

Ta

Answer (score 0):

Think I understand it now, thanks all. Also figured that fileExistsAtPath requires a file path so the URL has to be converted with myUrl.path

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:types];
[openPanel setCanSelectHiddenExtension:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:_window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
            // user did select an image...
            // get list of files in this dir

        NSURL *myUrl = [openPanel URL];
        NSString *workFile = myUrl.path;
        NSLog(@"workFile %@",workFile);
        BOOL isDir;
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:workFile isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
            NSLog(@"---------It's a dir---");

        }

    }
}];
```